# Weird internet connection issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, connection

I have an old Gateway PC with Windows 7 installed alongside the original (XP, I think?). A while ago my friend walked me through and helped me install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside the others because my Win7 was having issues with the display driver (it would unexpectedly crash while trying to watch videos on YouTube or other places). And I can't update it because the original computer settings are for XP or something, not Win7. :(

We recently switched from AT&T U-Verse to Comcast. I would have stayed with Ethernet, but somehow the adapter I have wouldn't connect to Comcast's thing during their installation. So I was given a wireless USB adapter. It worked fine, up until the last few days. It's not a problem on Win7 (using it right now). Connection's strong, things load.

On Ubuntu though, it SAYS it connects even before I login to my account, but when I login and bring up Firefox, it will load the homepage, and maybe one or two other pages I venture to before suddenly just... endlessly trying to load the page. I would normally go in and manually select 'disconnect' from the connections options menu to refresh/restart it like I've done a few times already. But lately, it won't respond, and then a little while later an error message comes up saying the request timed out/failed. Restarting my computer doesn't help it.

The other weird thing is that I've noticed the signal (when it's actually working properly before the last few days) is comparitively weaker than when I'm on Win7. But my location doesn't change. It's the same computer, same connection.